# Border around Powershell 2.0 Panel

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell 2.0 GUI which has a panel with a borderstyle of FixedSingle. The border renders black but I would like it to render it white but I am not seeing how to do that.

```
$dataPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$dataPanel.BorderStyle = "FixedSingle"
```

Comment: You would have to use `Graphics` to draw on top of the border.  There is no 'bordercolor' property, unfortunately.

Comment: If you are starting to learn making GUIs in PowerShell, maybe you should use WPF instead of WinForms. You _may_ have more options this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @gravity

Seems like an oversight that you can't change the border color! Either way I can do it then the following way:

```
$dataPanel = New-Object Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel
$dataPanel.BorderStyle = "None"
$dataPanel.add_paint({$whitePen = new-object System.Drawing.Pen([system.drawing.color]::white, 3)
$_.graphics.drawrectangle($whitePen,$this.clientrectangle)
})
```